# Get latest value based on other column's value with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with bookings and searches, ordered by users. I have one column that is true when is a booking and false when is a search, and I need to add another column 'previous_booking' that needs to have the value of the latest booking.

```
   user    visit_type  booking  search  visit_num         hotel
0  user1   busqueda     False    True         1             NaN
1  user1   busqueda     False    True         2             NaN
2  user1   reserva      True     False        3             15
3  user2   busqueda     False    True         1             NaN
4  user2   busqueda     False    True         2             NaN
5  user2   reserva      True     False        3             156
6  user2   reserva      True     False        3             156
7  user2   busqueda     False    True         4             NaN
8  user2   busqueda     False    True         5             NaN
9  user2   reserva      True     False        6             123
```

And I would need something like this:

```
user visit_type  booking  search  visit_num       hotel         latest_booking
0  user1   busqueda     False    True         1             NaN         NaN
1  user1   busqueda     False    True         2             NaN         NaN
2  user1   reserva      True     False        3             15          NaN
3  user2   busqueda     False    True         1             NaN         NaN
4  user2   busqueda     False    True         2             NaN         NaN
5  user2   reserva      True     False        3             156         NaN
6  user2   reserva      True     False        3             156         156
7  user2   busqueda     False    True         4             NaN         NaN
8  user2   busqueda     False    True         5             NaN         NaN 
9  user2   reserva      True     False        6             123         156
10 user2   reserva      True     False        6             135         123
```

Comment: try df['previousbooking']=df['latestbooking']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shift` + `ffill`, then converting `booking = False` rows to `NaN`.

```
df['latest_booking'] = df.groupby('user')['hotel'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().ffill())
df.loc[~df['booking'], 'latest_booking'] = np.nan

print(df)

    user visit_type booking search  visit_num  hotel  latest_booking
0  user1   busqueda   False   True          1    NaN             NaN
1  user1   busqueda   False   True          2    NaN             NaN
2  user1    reserva    True  False          3   15.0             NaN
3  user2   busqueda   False   True          1    NaN             NaN
4  user2   busqueda   False   True          2    NaN             NaN
5  user2    reserva    True  False          3  156.0             NaN
6  user2    reserva    True  False          3  156.0           156.0
7  user2   busqueda   False   True          4    NaN             NaN
8  user2   busqueda   False   True          5    NaN             NaN
9  user2    reserva    True  False          6  123.0           156.0
```